# How to write a JavaScript Array.from() Map Function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrow-functions

I'm building a tetris game in-browser using vanilla JS and HTML/CSS. The tutorial I am following treats the grid as a 2D matrix and uses the following code snippet to initialize it to be full of zeroes to start:

```
   return Array.from(
       {length : ROWS}, () => Array(COLS).fill(0)
   );
```

I'm hoping to get an explanation for how this code snippet actually achieves this. I understand the second parameter to be an arrow function which fills an array with 0s, but I don't really understand the first part. Does this code essentially do the same work as a for-loop, and if so, could this be replaced?

Apologies if this question is not appropriate, I couldn't find an exact duplicate and I'm not sure exactly how to google this due to my lack of understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.from` is a static method which allows you to create a new, shallow-copied `Array` instance from an array-like OR iterable object.

[See the documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

In your example the first argument is just an object itself. What `Array.from` is actually doing is looking for the `.length` property on the first argument (if its an array, this is obvious, but otherwise any iterable object has a `.length` property.

That example is kind of a cheat of sorts, where instead of passing an iterable object that actually has significance, you're just passing an empty object but specificying the `.length` property to be the number of rows.

Since the object has a `.length` property (even tho thats quite literally ALL it contains) the `Array.from` method knows what to do with it.

If you wanted something equivalent, you could use a for loop, like you described:

```
var newArray = [[]]

for (var i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
    newArray[i][j] = 0
  }
}
```

Their approach is just a bit more shorthand and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your snippet is missing some parts
`Array.from()` is a function that can make array from iterable objects, and then you can map through array. 
I guess it should look something like this

```
Array.from({length : ROWS}).map((item) => {item.fill(0)))
```

You can read more on Array.from() on mozzilla docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

and Array.map() here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/map

Comment: This would try to call `.fill(0)` on `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Array from can receive 3 params and creates you a new instance of an array.

- `arrayLike: ArrayLike<T>`
- `mapfn: (v: T, k: number) => U`
- `thisArg?: any`

**arrayLike**

arrayLike has a constructor that can receive two different params:

- readonly length: number;
- readonly [n: number]: T;

It's possible to enter two different kind to `from` as first param:

```js
console.log('{length: number}: ', Array.from({ length: 2 }));
console.log('[..., ...]: ', Array.from([1, 2]));
```

**mapfn**

This is a built in map function. You can use it to change the values of your first param:

```js
const multiplyByTwo = (entry) => entry * 2

console.log('without: ', Array.from([1,2]))
console.log('with multiply: ', Array.from([1,2], multiplyByTwo))
console.log('with multiply anonymus: ', Array.from([1,2], (entry) => entry * 2))
```

**thisArg**

You can bind a context to the function you are passing as second argument. It is similar to `fn.bind(context)`:

```js
function override (entry) {
  return this.num;
}
class Foo {
  num = 3;

  constructor() {
    console.log('arrayWithThis: ', Array.from([1, 2], override, this))
    console.log('arrayWithoutThis: ', Array.from([1, 2], override))
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
```